# Im confused about しちまって/ 実現しなかったら/とか

Tags: grammar

What is this しちまって？and this 実現しなかったら and the I didnt get the function of とか here. If someone could explain to me this things, Id appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, the し from 話しちまって（さ）actually belongs to 話し(はなし), meaning to speak. As of my understand, this　ちまって　is an informal version of しまう　(in the て　form、しまって). Look up for [~しまう Grammar here](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/unintended.html)

とか [is also another grammar point](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/complete/multiple_nouns), and is used to list actions or words

In the second phrase, 実現(じつげん) means "realization", and attaching する to it turns this word into the 実現する(じつげんする) verb "To make real, to realize". To turn it into a negative in past tense, we change する to しなかった, and in this case, to make it a conditional statement, [We use the ~たら grammar point](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/conditionals): 実現しなかったら

The translation of everything goes something like this

"Man, telling people about your dreams and such, don't you ever think what you would do if it never becomes a reality?"

Of course i may be wrong, take it with a grain of salt